# How to loop on JObject in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml

I am converting a xml doc to JObjects and then tying to loop over it. Below is the sample code and sample xml file. When there is multiple "Region" my foreach block works as expected as SerializeXmlNode() will create a array of region Objects, but when there is only one "Region" my foreach block fails with exception as it does not create any list of objects. I don't want to manipulate the xml my adding any attribute (json:Array='true'). What is the best way to handle this scenario.

```
var rawjson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(annotationsxml);
JObject regions = (JObject)rawjson["Document"]["Regions"];
foreach (JObject region in regions["Region"]) {
// do something
}
```

```
<Document>
    <Regions>
        <Region>"somedata"</Region>
        <Region>"something"</Region>
        ...
    </Regions>
</Document>
```

Comment: Why are you looping over a single `Region` element instead of simply looping over `regions`?

Comment: I am not looping in the XML data, i have converted XML to json. When we convert it to json if we have multiple "Region" tags then it will create a list of jobjects. But when there is single "Region" then it will not create list of jobject. Hence we cannot loop when there is only Region element

Comment: He's asking, correctly, why you're not using a simple `foreach (JObject region in regions)` and are selecting a specific region instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var jsonObject=JObject.Parse(rawjson);

List<string> regions = jsonObject["Document"]["Regions"]["Region"]
 .Select(x => (string) x ).ToList();  // ["somedata","something"]
    
foreach (string region in regions)
{
// do something
}
```